# Display List of MemberOrg's which have Paid yearly Dues?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC5 Application, I am currently dealing with 2 tables:

```
[MemberDues] -- [Id], [Year], [Display], [Amount]

[MemberDuesReceived] -- [Id], [MemberDuesId], [MemberOrgId], [PaidByUserId], [TransactionId], [Paid], [DatePaid], [PaymentMethod], [PayPalPaymentId], [PayPalPayerId], [PayPalPaymentState]
```

I have a View (below) where I display the records for Different `[MemberDues]`:

```
@model IEnumerable<PROJECTdev.Models.MemberDues>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Areas/Admin/Scripts/Dues/Index.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert" style="display: none;"></div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">

            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Display)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
            </th>
            <th>View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="MemberDuesManage/Edit/@item.Id" class="btn btn-success btn-sm noDecoration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  Edit</a>
                    <a href="MemberDuesManage/Delete/@item.Id" class="btn btn-default btn-sm noDecoration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span>  Delete</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Display, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control pull-left", style = "height: 20px; width: 20px;", onclick = "disableEnableDues(" + item.Id + ", this)" } })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="~/Admin/MemberDuesManage/DuesPaidMembers/@item.Id" class="btn btn-default btn-sm noDecoration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>  Paid</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I am attempting to do is have, when the [Paid] button (link) is clicked, a View is brought up which lists all the Member Organizations which have paid their dues. To do this, I have to query `[MemberDuesReceived]` for the appropriate `[MemberDuesId]` and return all records which have the matching `[MemberDuesId]` & `[Paid] == true`. This I have attempted to below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DuesPaidMembers(int id)
{
    MemberDues memberDues = await db.MemberDues.FindAsync(id);
    return View(db.MemberDuesReceived.Where(mdr => mdr.MemberDuesId == memberDues.Id && mdr.Paid).ToListAsync());
}
```

I then created a view called `DuesPaidMembers.cshtml` which is below:

```
@model IEnumerable<PROJECTdev.Models.MemberDuesReceived>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DuesPaidMembers";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>DuesPaidMembers</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MemberDues.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MemberOrganization.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PaidByUser.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TransactionId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Paid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DatePaid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PaymentMethod)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PayPalPaymentId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PayPalPayerId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PayPalPaymentState)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MemberDues.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MemberOrganization.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaidByUser.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Paid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatePaid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentMethod)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PayPalPaymentId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PayPalPayerId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PayPalPaymentState)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Currently however, when I click the button, my appropriate Controller Action (`DuesPaidMember()`) is called, but when the line `return View(db.MemberDuesReceived.Where(mdr => mdr.MemberDuesId == memberDues.Id && mdr.Paid).ToListAsync());` is hit, I receive the following error:

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PRISMdev.Models.MemberDuesReceived]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PRISMdev.Models.MemberDuesReceived]'.`

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I'm apparently doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is to blame.

```
return View(db.MemberDuesReceived
    .Where(mdr => mdr.MemberDuesId == memberDues.Id && mdr.Paid)
    .ToListAsync());
```

You are passing the result of `ToListAsync` as your model, which is a `Task<List<PRISMdev.Models.MemberDuesReceived>>`.

Instead, insert `await` so that the task is run and the resulting value of type `List<PRISMdev.Models.MemberDuesReceived>` is returned as your model:

```
return View(await db.MemberDuesReceived
    .Where(mdr => mdr.MemberDuesId == memberDues.Id && mdr.Paid)
    .ToListAsync());
```